# ReadTimoutError with opening multiple webdrivers in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, urllib3

My problem arises when multiple instances of the selenium webdriver get launched. I tried several things like changing the changing the method of requesting and going with and without headless, however the problem still remains. My program tries to parallelize the selenium webdriver and automate web interaction. Could somebody please help me to resolve this issue, either by handling the error or changing the code so that the error does not occur anymore. Thanks in advance.

```
    if url:
        options = Options()
        # options.headless = True
        options.set_preference('dom.block_multiple_popups', False)
        options.set_preference('dom.popup_maximum', 100000000)
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)

    pac = dict()

    try:
        # driver.get(url)
        # driver.execute_script('''window.location.href = '{0}';'''.format(url))
        driver.execute_script('''window.location.replace('{0}');'''.format(url))
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(lambda x: self.onload(pac, driver))
        pac['code'] = 200
    except ReadTimeoutError as ex:
        pac['code'] = 404
        print("Exception has been thrown. " + str(ex))

    return pac
```

urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=61322): Read timed out. (read timeout=)

Comment: The usual way to load a new url is `driver.get()`.  Is there a reason you're doing `window.location.replace()` instead?

Comment: not really i tried different things and it happens anyhow

Comment: I have sort of the same problem, I get a ReadTimeoutError when calling webdriver.get() after the internet connection has dropped out but comes back. All furhter calls to get() return the same error. Any clues?